# type or namespace 'Timers' name does not exist in the namespace 'System'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, timer, namespaces, system

I'm sure the answer to this is nowhere near as hard as my brain is making it seem but I can't seem to figure this one out.

I'm trying to set up a Timer for a game I'm starting, following mostly along with a tutorial to get the basics down. I've even created a new project with the EXACT code as the tutorial and I continuously get the same error(s). Despite seeing the code run perfectly in the tutorial...

I'd appreciate any help, and if you could let me know where I messed up and why, rather than just correct the code. I'm doing this as a learning project, so I'd like to know how to prevent this in the future. Thanks in advance!

Oh and I don't know if it matters, but I'm using Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express.

> 4 Errors, same message. Lines 10, 66, 67, and 72.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace rout3reset
{
public class RogueLike
{
    static bool isGameAlive = true; 
    static Player player;
    static System.Timers.Timer World; //timer declare

    public class Player //
    {
        public char CHR = '@'; // Symbol for player
        public Vector position; // X, Y coordinates tracker
        public string Name = "";
        public short Health = 25; // Base health
        public short Mana = 25; // Base Mana
        public Player() //player constructor
        {
            position = new Vector(1, 1); // sets spawn point
        }
        public void Update() // get handle controls
        {

        }
    }
    public class AI //
    {

    }

    public class Tree //
    {

    }

    public class Vector
    {
        public short X;
        public short Y;
        public Vector(short X, short Y) // Main constructor
        {
            this.X = X;
            this.Y = Y;
        }
        public Vector() // Overload of 1
        {
            this.X = 0;
            this.Y = 0;
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Initialize();
        do
        {
            player.Update();
        }
        while (isGameAlive);
    }

    static void Initialize()
    {
        World = new System.Timers.Timer(50); //Sets timer elapse point (50 milliseconds)
        World.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(Draw); //Start timer
        World.Start();
        player = new Player();
    }

    static void Draw(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e) // Handles world timer tick
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("########################################"); //40 Spaces wide by 20 spaces tall
        Console.WriteLine("#--------------------------------------#");
        Console.WriteLine("#--------------------------------------#");
        Console.WriteLine("#--------------------------------------#");
        Console.WriteLine("#--------------------------------------#");
        Console.WriteLine("#--------------------------------------#");
        Console.WriteLine("#--------------------------------------#");
        Console.WriteLine("#--------------------------------------#");
        Console.WriteLine("#--------------------------------------#");
        Console.WriteLine("#--------------------------------------#");
        Console.WriteLine("#--------------------------------------#");
        Console.WriteLine("#--------------------------------------#");
        Console.WriteLine("#--------------------------------------#");
        Console.WriteLine("#--------------------------------------#");
        Console.WriteLine("#--------------------------------------#");
        Console.WriteLine("#--------------------------------------#");
        Console.WriteLine("#--------------------------------------#");
        Console.WriteLine("#--------------------------------------#");
        Console.WriteLine("#--------------------------------------#");
        Console.WriteLine("########################################");

        Console.WriteLine("-{0} HP: {1} MP: {2}", player.Name, player.Health, player.Mana); //STAT BAR  

        Console.SetCursorPosition(player.position.X, player.position.Y); //sets proper char position for player symbol
        Console.Write(player.CHR); //draws the players char
    }
    static void Updateworld() //update non-player, non-antagonist objects (trees, etc)
    {

    }

}
```

}

Comment: @JonathonReinhart - Yeah, I just noticed that.

Comment: What type of project is this? (WinForms, WPF, Console, etc.) And what version of .NET are you targeting? Perhaps you're missing a reference to `System.dll` Check your project References folder in Solution Explorer for a reference to `System`

Comment: in my case same code is building fine.

Comment: would seem there is something very wrong does express install .net framework? this has been included in System.dll since version 1.1 : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSDN tells us that [`System.Timers.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) is from System.dll.

> Namespace:  System.Timers
>
> Assembly:  System (in System.dll)

It sounds like you're missing a reference to `System.dll`. Make sure you are referencing it:

[image]

Comment: wouldn't that be included in every new project?  I guess you could remove it on accident...

Comment: @David Yes, should be. But that's the only thing I can think of that would cause this error.

Comment: thank you guys! I'm looking into it now... I don't have a single reference in my solution explorer so my guess is that's what's wrong... I didn't even notice. Hopefully that works though.

Comment: @user2214232 I would just start over and create a new project. Who knows what else is broken. Then bring your source files over.

Comment: >.< Yup, that did the trick. Well then like i said, I figured it would be something utterly simple...

Comment: Glad I could help. I'm not sure how you managed to delete all your references, but I'd suggest you don't do that next time :-)

Comment: Lol, no kidding. ^_^ I'll be double checking that from now on. ^_^

Comment: @user2214232 - Don't forget to mark Jonathon's answer as accepted so he will get the credit.  Welcome to SO, and happy coding!